# Are "suggest a project for me" questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

There seems to be a lack of continuity when it comes to these questions.

Here is one that got upvoted highly:
[A good practice/project for PHP programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102255/a-good-practice-project-for-php-programmer)

And here is one on the brink of closure:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103825/ideas-for-windows-mobile-app

(Note: neither of the questions are mine.)

Are these questions appropriate? If not, what would be an appropriate place for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally no.  They are too broad - there is no "correct" answer, and there are a million possible variations on this type of question.

Occasionally one will get through the harsh moderation and 'make it' but that doesn't mean that they belong here.

Try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) for suggestions on programming projects.

Answer (score 2):

No, they're way over the 'subjective' line.  Maybe requests for specific interface or implementation details, but not whole project ideas.  Another good case for a

> Too Broad a Question

close case.

Comment: Actually, I like `[closed - Too Localized]` for this type of question. It is only of interest to that one user and *not* to anyone who follows.

Comment: @Robert: That isn't necessarily true, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: @Robert, yep, that's a good choice also.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience I was looking for a way to learn a bit of Python.

While searching stackoverflow I found a question of a similar vain, which directed me to [pythonchallenge.com](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/).

It was a real help and I am still enjoying solving the problems.

So sometimes these type of question can be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I could ask as well, are questions like "I cannot get this **jQuery** stuff working" (where the guy does not actually know why and how the thing *should* be working), are these questions valid and should these be upvoted? These are also too localized and, once answered, could be deleted as well.

I think, during the 3 weeks I've spent here, I've seen a thousand of this kind of questions ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, questions like "I wrote this code and can't find the error!" are orders of magnitude better than "What code should I write?". You could argue that the former is the real reason SO was created. ;)

Comment: Agreed with that. Just... sometimes it seems there should be jqueryoverflow.com :-)

Comment: Doesn't jqueryoverflow.com just redirect to Sampson's site?