# Name finding problem with comment notification feature

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, comments, notifications

I just received the following in my Response pane (from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/are-suggest-a-project-for-me-questions-acceptable/36359#36359)), but you can see it was meant for another user.  The @Robert line seems to have found 'Robert' in my name first, instead of Robert C. Cartaino.  I think the comment notification feature should match based on the closest match **from the first character in a name** (in posting order), and not just the first match found in posting order.

[alt text http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/7921/commentp.png](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/7921/commentp.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification is because you wrote the answer, and the comment was on the answer, not because he named you.

Comment: Hmmm, I imagine you're correct, hopefully Robert will chime in and verify

Comment: Robert let me know that he got the comment, so I'll vote to close my question (but leave it up in case anyone else has the same misconception).